# How to use GCP emulator in micronaut application for background function

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, micronaut, micronautgcp

I have two micronaut GCP applications

1. HTTP function
2. Background function

HTTP function is a regular micronuat application with the below dependency, and using pub/sub I am trying to trigger background function

```
implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
```

**Controller**

```
@Introspected
public class PubSubMessage {
    String data;
    Map<String, String> attributes;
    String messageId;
    String publishTime;
}

    @Controller("/")
    public record FileUploadController(IFileUploadClient iFileUploadClient){
    
        public String getFileName() {
            iFileUploadClient.pubSubMessage(new PubSubMessage());
            return "THis is file 1";
        }
    }

    @PubSubClient
    public interface IFileUploadClient {
        @Topic("projects/test-project/topics/micronaut-devices")
        void pubSubMessage(PubSubMessage pubSubMessage);
    }
```

**Background-function**

```
public class Function extends GoogleFunctionInitializer
        implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {


    @Override
    public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

class PubSubMessage {
    String data;
    Map<String, String> attributes;
    String messageId;
    String publishTime;
}
```

I am running the HTTP function as regular micronaut application with `runtime("netty")`, however for the background function, I have setup the gradle task

```
tasks.register("runFunction", JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker'
  classpath(configurations.invoker)
  inputs.files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output)
  args(
    '--target', project.findProperty('run.functionTarget') ?: 'fete.bird.Function',
    '--port', project.findProperty('run.port') ?: 8081
  )
  doFirst {
    args('--classpath', files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output).asPath)
  }
}
```

I am using an emulator with the below command

```
Gcloud beta emulators pub sub start --host-port=127.0.0.1:8086 --project=test-project
```

[image]

The emulator has the below topics
[image]

Exception is thrown when publish the message

```
 iFileUploadClient.pubSubMessage(new PubSubMessage());
```

In the micronaut documentation it is mentioned that **The framework supports automatic switching of the TransportChannelProvider to use PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST if this variable is set on the environment**.

**Make sure that you also set GCP_PROJECT_ID to be the same as the project you have configured the emulator to use. Otherwise the framework may pick up the projectId used by the default credentials.**

The framework is somehow picking the different project that I have set using the command `--project=test-project`

**Error**

```
ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project 'project:adept-button-401609' not found or deleted.
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project 'project:adept-button-401609' not found or deleted.
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:408)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712)
    at io.micronaut.gcp.pubsub.intercept.PubSubClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(PubSubClientIntroductionAdvice.java:185)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at fete.bird.IFileUploadClient$Intercepted.pubSubMessage(Unknown Source)
    at fete.bird.FileUploadController.getFileName(FileUploadController.java:26)
    at fete.bird.$FileUploadController$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:442)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanContextExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:4282)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:223)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.executeRouteAndConvertBody(RouteExecutor.java:480)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.callRoute(RouteExecutor.java:470)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RequestLifecycle.lambda$normalFlow$2(RequestLifecycle.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.core.execution.ImperativeExecutionFlowImpl.flatMap(ImperativeExecutionFlowImpl.java:72)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RequestLifecycle.lambda$normalFlow$4(RequestLifecycle.java:146)
```

The error is `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project 'project:adept-button-401609' not found or deleted.`

I have exposed the below command as well

```
$(gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init)

export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:8086
export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=test-project
```

I have also exported the project id as `export GCP_PROJECT_ID="test-project"` still the same issue

When application is running the default credential is used

[image]

**.properties** file

```
gcp.project-id=test-project
```

GitHub - https://github.com/anandjaisy/gcp-background-function

In the Application Default Credentials works  on mac

[image]

It is using this json

```
{
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "client_secret": "xxx",
  "quota_project_id": "adept-button-401609",
  "refresh_token": "xxx",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

However, it should use the emulator version. Due to some reason, the micronaut application is not picking up

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with micronaut. I suspect your code (not the emulator) is finding [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials) as a result of using Google's SDKs. You aren't setting `GCP_PROJECT_ID` as instructed. If that doesn't address the issue, if you're running locally, check whether you're setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I think you would get a different error if you're using user credentials (`application_default_credentials.json`).

Comment: @DazWilkin I have also done export GCP_PROJECT_ID="test-project" however same issue

Comment: Please don't use images when it's trivial to copy-and-paste text. Images may not outlive the question and they limit others referencing the content.

Comment: Your question does not explain where/how you're running the processes but I continue to strongly suspect the issue is a result of ADC. I encourage you to read the ADC documentation to determine where you're going wrong.

Comment: @DazWilkin Where can I find ADC documentation? I am using Mac OS with HTTP Microanut application. I am following the documentation of https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/latest/guide/#emulator

Comment: I included the link in my original comment but [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials)

Comment: @DazWilkin When I was using Gcloud CLI I exported the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with .json file. However, now I need to run an emulator. I am not able to run it, not sure how to do it. GitHub Link - https://github.com/anandjaisy/gcp-background-function

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the export env variable needs to be in same session as the application is running.

**Terminal**

```
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085

export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=white-stacker-412404
```

Then

```
./gradlew run
```

By setting all the env variables in the same terminal session, the application works.

**Intellj IDE**

Edit configuration and set the below env variable

```
PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=white-stacker-412404;PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085
```